# When column reaches certain amount of rows whit 0 values change values to Na

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, replace

I´m trying to change certain 0 values to Na´s in a data frame with the following rules: When certain site * year combination repeats all the species with count value of 0 then value should be Na. I have columns: site, year, count and species. If there are no data from one site in certain year the count should be NA like in ss 2000, but if there is data found in certain year from one site, like in pp 2001, then the frog count should stay as 0. Real dataset is huge so I can´t just pick the rows that I want to change. Ideas how to do it? Here in this table only ss 2000 is empty and therefore count should be Na.

```
site year count species 
ss   2000 0     frogs  
ss   2000 0     dogs   
ss   2000 0     cats   
pp   2000 1     frogs  
pp   2000 2     dogs   
pp   2000 0     cats   
ss   2001 0     frogs  
ss   2001 1     dogs   
ss   2001 0     cats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind,
  by(df,list(df$site,df$year),function(x){
    if (all(x$count==0)){
      x$count=NA
    }
    x
  })
)

  site year count species
4   pp 2000     1   frogs
5   pp 2000     2    dogs
6   pp 2000     0    cats
1   ss 2000    NA   frogs
2   ss 2000    NA    dogs
3   ss 2000    NA    cats
7   ss 2001     0   frogs
8   ss 2001     1    dogs
9   ss 2001     0    cats
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really struggling with my limited skills!